# Perl: Matching four different files and obtaining particular Information in output file

Tags: perl

I have four files. File 1 (named as inupt_22.txt) is an input file containing two columns (space delimited). First column is the alphabetically sorted list of ligandcode (three letter/number code for a particular ligand). Second column is a list of PDBcodes (Protein Data Bank code) respective of each ligandcode (unsorted list though).[image]

File 1 (input_22.txt):

```
    803      1cqp    
    AMH      1b2i    
    ASC      1f9g    
    ETS      1cil    
    MIT      1dwc    
    TFP      1ctr     
    VDX      1db1     
    ZMR      1a4g
```

File 2(named as SD_2.txt) is a SDF (Structure Data file) for fragments of each ligand. A ligand can contain one or more than one fragments. For instance, here 803 is the ligandcode and it has two fragments. So the file will look like: four dollar sign (`$$$$`) followed by ligandcode (i.e 803 in this example) in next line. every fragment follows the same thing. Next, in the 5th line of each fragment (third line from `$$$$.\n803`), there is a number that represents number of rows in next block of rows, like 7 in first fragment and 10 in next fragment of 803 ligand. Now, next block of rows contains a column (61-62) which contains specific number that refers to atoms in fragments. For example in first fragment of 803, these numbers are 15,16,17,19,20,21,22. These numbers need to be matched in file 3.[image]

File 2 (SD_2.txt) looks like:

```
$$$$    
803    
  SciTegic05101215222D    


  7  7  0  0  0  0            999 V2000    
    3.0215   -0.5775    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 15  0  0     
    2.3070   -0.9900    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 16  0  0     
    1.5926   -0.5775    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 17  0  0      
    1.5926    0.2475    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 19  0  0      
    2.3070    0.6600    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 20  0  0      
    2.3070    1.4850    0.0000 O   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 21  0  0      
    3.0215    0.2475    0.0000 O   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 22  0  0      
  1  2  1  0      
  1  7  1  0       
  2  3  1  0     
  3  4  1  0      
  4  5  1  0      
  5  6  2  0     
  5  7  1  0      
M  END      
> <Name>      
803      

> <Num_Rings>      
1      

> <Num_CSP3>       
4     

> <Fsp3>       
0.8         

> <Fstereo>       
0      

$$$$      
803       
  SciTegic05101215222D       

 10 11  0  0  0  0            999 V2000       
   -1.7992    -1.7457    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0        
   -2.5137    -1.3332    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  2  0  0        
   -2.5137    -0.5082    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  3  0  0        
   -1.7992    -0.0957    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  5  0  0        
   -1.0847   -0.5082    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  6  0  0       
   -0.3702    -0.0957    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  7  0  0        
    0.3442     -0.5082    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  8  0  0       
    0.3442     -1.3332    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  9  0  0        
   -0.3702     -1.7457    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 11  0  0      
   -1.0847    -1.3332    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0 12  0  0       
  1  2  1  0        
  1 10  1  0      
  2  3  1  0      
  3  4  1  0      
  4  5  2  0      
  5  6  1  0      
  5 10  1  0     
  6  7  2  0      
  7  8  1  0      
  8  9  1  0     
 10  9  1  0      
M  END        
> <Name>       
803       

> <Num_Rings>     
2     

> <Num_CSP3>     
6     

> <Fsp3>     
0.6      

> <Fstereo>      
0.1
```

File 3 is CIF (Crystallographic Information file). This file can be obtained from following link: [File_3](ftp://ftp.wwpdb.org/pub/pdb/data/monomers/components.cif)
This file is a collection of individual cif files for several ligand molecules. Each part in file starts with `data_ligandcode`. For our example it will be `data_803`. After 46 lines from the start of each small file in collection, there is a block that gives structural information about the molecule. The number of rows in this block is not fixed. However, this block ends with an Hash sign (`#`). In this block two columns are important which are 53-56 and 62-63. 62-63 column contains numbers that can be matched from numbers obtained from file 2. And, 53-56 contains atom names like `C1 (Carbon 1)` etc. This column can be used to match with file 4.

File 4 is a Grow.out file that contains information about interaction of each ligand with their target protein. The file name is the PDBcode given in file 1 against each ligand. For example for ligand 803 the PDBcode is 1cqp. So, the grow.out file will be having name of 1cqp. [1cqp](http://www.ebi.ac.uk/thornton-srv/databases/pdbsum/1cqp/grow.out) 
In this file those rows are important those contain ligandcode (for example 803) and and the atom name obtained from 53-56 column of file three.

Task: I need a script that reads ligandcode from File 1, goes to file 2 search for `$$$$ . \nLigandcode` and then obtain numbers from column 61-62 for each fragment. Then in next step my script should pass these number to file 3 and match the rows containing these number in column 62-63 of file 3 and then pull out the information in column 53-56 (atom names). And last step will be opening of file 4 with the name of PDBcode and then printing the rows containing ligandcode and the atom names obtained from file 3. The printing should be done in an output file.

I am a Biomedical Research student. I don't have computer science background. However, I have to use Perl programming for some task. For the above mentioned task I wrote a script, but it is not working properly and I can not find the reason behind it. The script I wrote is :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Text::Table;
use Carp qw(croak);

{

    my $a;
    my $b;
    my $input_file = "input_22.txt";
    my @lines = slurp($input_file);
    for my $line (@lines){
        my ($ligandcode, $pdbcode) = split(/\t/, $line);
        my $i=0;
        my $k=0;

        my @array;
        my @array1;

        open (FILE, '<', "SD_2.txt");


        while (<FILE>) {
            my $i=0;
            my $k=0;

            my @array;
            my @array1;

            if ( $_=~/\x24\x24\x24\x24/ . /\n$ligandcode/) {


                my $nextline1 = <FILE>;
                my $nextline2 = <FILE>;
                my $nextline3 = <FILE>;
                my $nextline4= <FILE>;

                my $totalatoms= substr( $nextline4, 1,2);
                print $totalatoms,"\n";
                while ($i<$totalatoms)
                  {

                      my $nextlines= <FILE>;

                      my $sub= substr($nextlines, 61, 2);
                      print $sub;
                      $array[$i] = $sub;
                      open (FH, '<', "components.txt");

                      while (my $ship=<FH>) {
                          my $var="data_$ligandcode";
                          if ($ship=~/$var/)


                            {

                                while ($k<=44)
                                  {
                                      $k++;
                                      my $nextline = <FH>;

                                  }

                                my $j=0;
                                my $nextline3;
                                do
                                  {

                                      $nextline3=<FH>;
                                      print $nextline3;

                                      my $part= substr($nextline3, 62, 2);
                                      my $part2= substr($nextline3, 53, 4);
                                      $array1[$j] = $part;
                                      if ($array1[$j] eq $array[$i])
                                        {
                                            print $part2, "\n";
                                            open (GH, '<', "$pdbcode"); 
                                            open (OH, ">>out_grow.txt");
                                            while (my $grow = <GH>)
                                              {
                                                  if ( $grow=~/$ligandcode/){
                                                      print OH $grow if $grow=~/$part2/; 
                                                  }}
                                            close (GH);
                                            close (OH);
                                        }

                                      $j++;
                                  } while $nextline3 !~/\x23/;
                            }
                      }
                      $i++;
                      close (FH);
                  }

            }}

        close (FILE);

    }
}


##Slurps a file into a list
sub slurp {
    my ($file) = @_;
    my (@data, @data_chomped);
    open IN, "<", $file or croak "can't open $file\n";
    @data = <IN>;
    for my $line (@data){
        chomp($line);
        push (@data_chomped, $line);
    }
    close IN;
    return (@data_chomped);
}
```

I want to make it a script that works fast and works for 1000 fragments altogether, if I make a list of 400 molecules in file 1. Kindly help me to make this script working. I ll be grateful.

Comment: Thank you for clearly laying out your needs and posting your attempt!

Comment: Post `input_22.txt` and `SD_2.txt` also as text ([see editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)). No one has the patience to transcribe that long data from screen-shots.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using [Chemistry-Mol](https://metacpan.org/release/Chemistry-Mol), and [Chemistry::File::SDF](https://metacpan.org/module/Chemistry::File::SDF)?

Comment: @Brad Gilbert: No there is no reason. It is just like I am new to perl, so don't know much about it. If you see my script I have used really basic syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You need to break your code into manageable steps.

1. Create data-structures from the files

   ```
   use Slurp;

   my @input = map{
     [ split /\s+/, $_, 2 ]
   } slurp $input_filename;

   # etc
   ```
2. Process each element of `input_22.txt`, using those data structures.

I really think you should look into [PerlMol](http://www.perlmol.org). After all, half the reason to use Perl is [CPAN](http://cpan.org).

---

Things you did well

- Using 3-arg [`open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html)
- `use strict;`
- `use warnings;`

Things you shouldn't have done

- (Re)defined `$a` and `$b`
  They are already defined for you.
- Reimplemented [`slurp`](http://p3rl.org/Slurp) (poorly)
- Read the same file in multiple times.
  You opened `SD_2.txt` once for every line of `input_22.txt`.
- Defined symbols outside of the scope where you use them.
  `$j`, `$k`, `@array` and `@array1` are defined twice, but only one of the definitions is being used.
- Used [`open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) and [`close`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/close.html) without some sort of error checking.
  Either `open ... or die;` or `use autodie;`
- You used bareword filehandles. `IN`, `FILE` etc
  Instead use `open my $FH, ...`

Most of those aren't that big of a deal though, for a one-off program.